# Scroll view and Stack view

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uistackview

I've read everything I could find about stacks with scroll views but nothing helps me.

I want to have vertical scroll because I have some labels in stack view and sometimes there are all labels sometimes there are not. According to this, I want to make scroll when needed. Here is a visual representation of my problem.

[image]

How could I achieve this? Do I have to code something or do some adjustments on storyboard?

Comment: You can do that only with storyboard and constraints, the contentSize of the scrollView is the intrinsic content size of the UIStackView, I can share the solution using storyboard if needed. hope that helps

Comment: Well it works with solution provided below. If I will experiment with it I will post something here so you'll know I need help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `contentSize` property of `UIScrollView` for this purpose.

```
  scrollview.contentSize = CGSizeMake(contentWidth, contentHeight)
```

This property sets content size of the scrollview.

Lets take example, consider you have scrollview whose height is **480** and width is **320**

If you want horizontal scrolling then set `contentWidth` greater then 320 and if you want vertical scrolling set `contentHeight` greater then 480

For your problem it should be like this

```
  yourscrollview.contentSize = CGSizeMake(your scrollview Width, Y of Last label + height of Last Label)
```

And don't forget to set

```
      scrBudgetList.scrollEnabled = true;
```

Comment: I never want a horizontal scroll. So I have Scroll view in place, I set constraints but I'm lost in CGSizeMake function. I have something like

scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(scrollView.frame.width, newsLabel.frame.height)

Comment: I did it. I just had to set stack width same as scroll view. Thanks